# Filament Relations - parent/child

Tags: php, relationship, laravel-filament

I have two models Customers and Orders. The relationship is 'customers.id' -> 'orders.customer_id' (primary field in Orders). I have 2 resources - CustomerResource and OrderResource, self-explanatory.

I choose 'Customers' to add/edit customer details, while 'Orders' to add/edit order details. In the OrderResource, the 'customer_id' is populated through the Select and relationship elements, self-explanatory.

I want to add/edit Orders from the CustomerResource, which means I click a customer name from the list and the OrderResourceRelation will list all existing orders. When I click the 'Add' button, the OrderResourceRelation must allow me enter order details on-the-fly in the list screen instead of 'Add' pop-up window.

Please assist.

Thanks,